# Correct way to use sessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

Im trying to learn spring 3 and DAO and BO classes and how to autowire with it and I was wondering is this the correct way to wire the sessionFactory as i have read that it is better to use

```
public void save(Customer customer) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(customer);
}
```

rather than

```
public void save(Customer customer){
    getHibernateTemplate().save(customer);
}
```

So is the following the correct way to wire the sessionFactory?

CustomHibernateDaoSupport class

```
package com.fexco.helloworld.web.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public abstract class CustomHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport
{    
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
public void seSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    this.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
}
```

CustomerDaoImpl class

```
package com.fexco.helloworld.web.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.fexco.helloworld.web.model.Customer;
import com.fexco.helloworld.web.util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport;

@Repository("customerDao")
public class CustomerDaoImpl extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport implements CustomerDao{


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(Customer customer) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(customer);
}
```

Is this correct or am i making a mistake somewhere because i cant get it to work?
Thanks

Comment: If you're using Hibernate 3, you don't need to use HibernateTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation of why we don't need any templates with Hibernate 3
http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/